# Selenium Chrome WebDriver Cannot start Driver service on port

Tags: selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am not able start ChromeWebDriver/IE/Firefox and it throws me a error message

This issue occurs only with

- Selenium C# Binding with ChromeDriver
- Occurs when I am connected to my Organization's VPN

Doesn't occur with Python ChromeDriver binding

```
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException:Cannot start the Driver Service on http://localhost:59343
```

Comment: your port 59343 looks occupied, it does not happen if you are not using VPN?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be the case that a process of the WebDriver is still running in the background. Fire up Task Manager to see and end it if does.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, when I used Selenium.Webdriver 3.00-beta1 with Firefox in Visual Studio. After update to version 3.00-beta2 it start work good.

Answer (score 0):

I'm work using VPN in Windows, and I solved this issue setting an environment variable.

Variable: **NO_PROXY**

Value: **localhost**

---

Pac-Man team.

Comment: was it not working at all? or it work for sometime and then after start throwing the error?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with Selenium in PowerShell over corporate VPN, without VPN got "cannot find host proxy-dmz.corporate.com" instead. Turns out the hint in https://stackoverflow.com/a/70463561/2894535 was correct, but I had to set environment variables **BEFORE** loading the DLL. If the DLL is already loaded, you need to quit PowerShell and start new instance.

```
# This works
Remove-Item 'env:http*_proxy'
Add-Item -LiteralPath 'WebDriver.dll'
$driver = [ChromeDriver]::new()

# This also works
$env:NO_PROXY = 'localhost'
Add-Item -LiteralPath 'WebDriver.dll'
$driver = [ChromeDriver]::new()


# Those will not work
Add-Item -LiteralPath 'WebDriver.dll'
Remove-Item 'env:http*_proxy'
$driver = [ChromeDriver]::new()

# Or
Add-Item -LiteralPath 'WebDriver.dll'
$env:NO_PROXY = 'localhost'
$driver = [ChromeDriver]::new()
```